# About ERC-20 token exchange

Tags: contract-development

I'm new to ERC-20 and Solidity.  When I think about some ideas, I have two questions which may be naive.

Suppose I'm developing two coins A and B.

1. In contract of A, could it automatically send some tokens of A when it receives some tokens of B?
2. In contract of A, could it automatically send some tokens of B when it receive some tokens of A?

Answer (score 1):

While two questions look very similar, the answers are quite different.

For the second question the answer is definitely yes.  Contract that manages tokens A is aware of all transfer of these tokens.  Thus, contract of A may detect that somebody transfers tokens A to it, and may do something in response, transfer tokens B, in our case.

For the second questions the answer it not that simple.  Unlike ether, when ERC-20 tokens are transferred to contract's address, the contract's code is not invoked, and thus the contract cannot immediately respond to the transfer.  Though, there are several ways, how contract may receive tokens and react somehow on these incoming token transfers.

The most common way is to use approve/transferFrom pattern:

1. The user who wants to send B tokens to contract of A and get A tokens in exchange, does not send tokens directly via `transfer` function.  Instead, he allows contract of A to take his B tokens by calling `approve` function on the contract of B and passing A contract address and amount of tokens as parameters.  At this points tokens are not transferred yet, but contract of A becomes eligible to take the tokens.
2. Then, the user calls some function on contract of A asking this contract to take his tokens.
3. Then contract of A takes B tokens by calling `transferFrom` on contract of B
4. Finally, contract of A sends A tokens to the user.

Actually, this method will work even when contract A exchanges tokens managed by contract B to tokens managed by contract C, i.e. contract A does not manage any tokens at all but just exchanges them.

Another way is to implement [ERC-223](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223) API in contract of B tokens.  This standard defines standard way how smart contracts are notified about incoming token transfer.  it requires recipient contract, contract of A in our case, to implement function with the following signature:

```solidity
function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data)
```

This function is called every time ERC-223 compliant tokens are transferred to the contract that implements this function.  Inside the function recipient contract may do something useful, e.g. send some other tokens to the `_from` address.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. What you basically need is a standard ERC20 token with some extra features:

1) Token purchasing in some way

2) When a user purchases tokens from contract A the contract also notifies contract B to modify balance of the user. Also various checks to make sure both actions are valid.

You don't need any excplicit "sending" of tokens - they are only balances within a contract.